# How can I get my quotes to display correctly in PHP using MYSQL information and put them inside an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Paraphrasing...

OK i have information in a database it reads: This is random text with a "random quote"

```
$var = 'This is random text with a "random quote"'

onClick="show(\''.$var.'\')
```

but when displayed (viewing source) it shows:

```
onclick="show('This is random text with a  " random="" quote"')
```

I have tried mysqli_real_escape_string and str_replace, str_replace works if i am removing the "

Any help, alterations or reworks I would be grateful its driving me nuts right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this for an HTML context, you should be using `&quot;` to escape those. This is done with the [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

If you want it as a JavaScript string, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the string.

`mysqli_real_escape_string` should be used *only* for database calls, and *only* as a last resort. Remember, parameterized queries are the best way to compose SQL statements.

You really shouldn't need to ever set an `onclick` event directly. A library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) has much better ways of doing this:

```
$('#my_element').click(function() { show('...'); });
```

Comment: I have tried the htmlspecialchars() it does change the to &quot; but still not working.. :/ 


So on index.php I have the images load up from 

$(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
});

The Function refreshTable(); reloads the information every 5 mins from page.php

So all this information I am working with is on a separate page and loaded in dynamically on the index.php page.

Comment: Ahh I missed something, I still needed to use str_replace I had an apostrophe in there too was like this "random' quote" so I escaped the apostrophe and it works thank you. No how do I best answer this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<script>
function show(str)
{
   alert(str);
}
</script>
<?php 
     $var = "This is random text with a \'random quote\'";
     echo '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="show(\''.$var.'\')">click</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try: `addslashes($var)`. It should add slashes to the quotes so they are escaped in the javascript.

Comment: `addslashes` is a really hack way of doing this.